# Setting multiple WMS layers over basemap of OpenLayers 3?

Tags: javascript, wms, openlayers

I'm developing a web-based application. In this project I'm trying to create multiple WMS image layer over the map with legends.

As you can see below its showing the WMS layer over its basemap .  This is what I am trying to get.

[image]

Below I have tried to displayed one sample from GeoServer and second one is for land use/land cover but i'm not able to set basemap for this layer as you can see. There is only WMS layered displayed when I checked on landuse/ landcover button.

[image]

Creating one layer over the basemap it is possible to show but I need to set this for multiple WMS Layers.

So my main problem is I'm unable to write code for showing WMS layer over the basemap.  This is my code so far.

```
<script src="sideicon_file/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="jsuntitled/ol.js"></script>
<script>
    //this is my first layer as you can see from screenshot no.2  
var landuseLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
    coordinates: [-124.73142200000001, 24.955967,
                    -66.969849, 49.371735],
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/wms',
      params: {'LAYERS': 'topp:states'},
     maxZoom: 19
    }),
    visible: false,
  });

  var  soilLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
  coordinates: [79.14511833527447, 20.987418098133496, 79.2018842619151, 21.050233196545],
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sagy/wms',
          params: {'LAYERS': 'sagy:pachgaon_LULC'},
          maxZoom: 19
        }),
        visible: false
      });

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [landuseLayer, soilLayer],
  renderer: 'canvas',
  target: document.getElementById('map'),
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
                attributionOptions: ({
                    collapsible: false
                })
            }).extend([
                new ol.control.ZoomSlider(),
                new ol.control.ZoomToExtent({
                    extent: [
                        813079.7791264898, 5929220.284081122,
                        848966.9639063801, 5936863.986909639

                    ]
                }),

                new ol.control.Rotate(),
                new ol.control.OverviewMap(),
                new ol.control.ScaleLine(),
                new ol.control.FullScreen(),
                new ol.control.MousePosition({
                    coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(4),
                    projection: 'EPSG:4326'
                })
            ]),

  interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([
                new ol.interaction.Select({
                    condition: ol.events.condition.mouseMove
                })
            ]),

            view: new ol.View({
                center: new ol.geom.Point([-10997148, 4569099])
                    .transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:4326').getCoordinates(),
                zoom: 4
            }),

            target: 'map'
        });

$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  var layer = {

    landuse: landuseLayer,
    soil: soilLayer,

  }[$(this).attr('id')];
  layer.setVisible(!layer.getVisible());
});
```

Comment: What is the projection system of both layers?

Comment: 'EPSG:4326', projection of both layer

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what is happening? That may make this easier to understand.

Comment: @EvilGenius hi .. will you please help me if you know the solution. :| or in which way i should try to do this.

Comment: Have you tried debugging in a browser?  to see if there are any errors. Chrome is pretty good (right click inspect element).

Comment: @Sethinacan yah i have tried that too.. but still not able to solve this problem

Comment: Appears to be cross-posted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34881411/wanted-to-set-multiple-wms-layers-over-the-basemap

Comment: I think this is definitely the more suitable home for it.  Once you have taken the [tour] I will encourage you to read this [Meta GIS SE advice on how to structure questions here](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115) that the [tour] and [help/on-topic] link through to.

Comment: I am not a potential answerer of this question.  The best way to get help here is by making your question as clear as possible to read, while at the same time demonstrating precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I think your problem is in CRS. Some layers can be on other place than basemap. Also you should display layers transparently to eliminate problem where layer which have undefined extent are loading while tiles which are covering the map (hiding other layers) - check your network panel in developer tools. Also check some online solutions http://geoserver.vsb.cz/~koc0161/amo/

Comment: @DavidK thanks  for the link .. somewhere it helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, we just need to set

```
layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
})landuseLayer, soilLayer],
```

in place of  `layers: [landuseLayer, soilLayer],`

Image will display over the map :)